# Dependent drop-down values in Adaptive card for Msteams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am having a task module popup and there are two drop-down lists. On selection of any value from drop down 1, I want to dynamically load the inputs for drop down 2 by doing a API call.
Is this possible in task module popup?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with adaptive card.
To achieve this, you need to create custom pages and on selection of drop-down1 value you have load the drop-down 2.

Comment: Didnt get you by custom pages. How can we create custom pages and render on msteams app. -@Nivedipa-MSFT

Comment: You can create custom html page and display in Task module.

Comment: Oh was not aware of this.Could you please add documentation link for this. It would be really helpful.

Comment: Please refer below document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?pivots=node-java-script